# How do I coerce types of iterator elements to & from a newtype?

Tags: vector, collections, rust, type-conversion, newtype

Doing some experiments with newtypes and looking for the most efficient, most ergonomic way of dealing with converting elements in collections. For singular values, pretty standard type conversion traits seem to work just fine:

```rust
pub struct Tag(String);

impl From<Tag> for String {
    fn from(v: Tag) -> String {
        v.0
    }
}

impl From<String> for Tag {
    fn from(v: String) -> Tag {
        Tag(v)
    }
}

impl AsRef<String> for Tag {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &String {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a Tag> for String {
    fn from(t: &Tag) -> String {
        t.0.clone()
    }
}
```

But, I start to hit issues when I want to deal with lists of items. Say (for the purposes of illustration) I have a function which processes tags, and some more abstract function which deals with writing strings to a DB:

```rust
fn process_item(tags: &Vec<Tag>) {
    process_array_of_strings(tags);
}

fn process_array_of_strings(strings: &Vec<String>) {
    // ...
}
```

This won't compile because Rust can't coerce `tags` to a `Vec<String>`, and it feels to me like there should be some way of doing this more easily than:

```rust
fn process_item(tags: &Vec<Tag>) {
    let str_tags: Vec<String> = tags.iter().map(|t| t.into()).collect();
    process_array_of_strings(&str_tags);
}
```

...which besides being verbose, involves much more intermediary memory than I'd like. The reverse conversion is also an issue, but presumably would be implemented in the same way.

There may be some additional things in play here, for example whether I should be sending `Vec`s of references rather than values, and whether or not it's a good idea to implement type conversions from reference types.

Comment: Note that it is [not idiomatic for functions to accept an immutable reference to `Vec`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/1233251).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just use generic:

```rust
pub struct Tag(String);

impl AsRef<str> for Tag {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn process_item(tags: &[Tag]) {
    process_array_of_strings(tags);
}

fn process_array_of_strings<'a, T>(strings: &[T])
where
    T: AsRef<str>,
{
    // ...
}
```

- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o)
- Here we simply ask that `T` implement `AsRef<str>` (more generic than `String`) so you can just use [`as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#tymethod.as_ref) after on it.

Comment: I see! Thankyou. So, for clarity- the `str` / `String` isn't so much the culprit here as the `[T]` / `Vec<T>`, correct?

And I also presume this cannot be alleviated without changing the definition of the called function (in this case, `process_array_of_strings`), which is why use of the non-generic form is discouraged?

Comment: @pospi if you want use trait, use a generic is the most simple and zero cost solution.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. What I'm saying is that in this particular case (which I just confirmed by trying it out), it's not actually the `String` that is preventing the conversion into `process_array_of_strings` from working. It will *work* with `String`, just not efficiently. It's the `Vec<T>` parameter type that means the argument can't be coerced, because the wrapper type gets in the way of type inference.